# Is there a way to automatically correct the color balance?

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image

I'm looking for a solution to automatically adjust the [color balance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_balance)?
I would like to use the pictures for color analysis and comparison, therefore color balance is important.
I was hoping a feature such as [histogram equalization with scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/color_exposure/plot_equalize.html) to correct and balance the colors. The result doesn't have to look good or natural, it must just always be the same.

Does anyone have a solution ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is a good article on color balancing at [Illuminant Estimation: Simplest Color Balance](http://web.stanford.edu/~sujason/ColorBalancing/simplestcb.html).  The code is in MATLAB but a guy named Roy ported it to C++ using OpenCV here: [Simplest Color Balance with OpenCV [w/code]](http://www.morethantechnical.com/2015/01/14/simplest-color-balance-with-opencv-wcode/).

David Young-Chan Kay took that same code and ported it to Python 2.7.8 and OpenCV 2.4.10 here: https://gist.github.com/DavidYKay/9dad6c4ab0d8d7dbf3dc

Below is an original image like that in your reference, and below it is the output of the algorithm. 
[image]
[image]